# MLT transparency of watermarks and tracks not working

Tags: png, transparency, alpha, melt, mlt

I am trying to get melt to work, but it seems, it doesn't support transparency (alpha channels)! Using the official watermarking example, I get a black background behind the PNG and don't see any video through.

```
melt \
test.mp4 out=1000 \
-track \
watermark1.png out=1000 \
-transition composite fill=1 in=0 out=1000 a_track=0 b_track=1 geometry=85%/5%:10%x10% sliced_composite=1 \
$*
```

I installed melt via "brew" version 6.20.0 on a mac, obviously.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your command works perfectly for me. I am on windows and I used the melt.exe command that comes with Shotcut. Perhaps there is something missing in your version of melt. Consider downloading Shotcut from here:

https://shotcut.org/download/

Then, use the included version of melt to try your command.

Also, are you absolutely sure that your png file has a transparent background? Sorry, but I just have to ask.